# How to get debugging c++ to work in VSCode on a mac?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

Can someone explain how to get building and debugging to work in VSCode **on a Mac**?

Let's assume we successfully installed cpp tools:

[image]

-Including creating a proper task file that works on a mac.
-The required changes to launch.json
-Any other step required.

(Don't get me wrong, I'm not lazy, I have been trying for more then 2 hours now and it seems that a proper answer for this question can help a lot of people.)

Comment: What have you tried? I downloaded VSCode, installed python, opened a file, wrote some python, typed Command-F5 and it ran with output in the debug console.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the C/C++ extension downloaded, you can use the configurations to generate a project.json in debug window of VsCode. If you do not currently have a project.json under the project's .vscode folder, hit F5 and a dropdown list should show up. There you can select C++ (GDB/LLDB), and this should generate a project.json for you to use.

If you want to just hit F5 so it automatically compiles and debugs your program, you will need to add a tasks.json. This can be done by hitting F1 and selecting `Tasks: Configure Task Runner` and select `Other`. Replace "echo" with "gcc" (or clang) and replace the args with your .cpp files and don't forget to add -g.

You can find more information in their documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

Answer (score 0):

I don't count the time I lost looking for an answer to this question!

I found the [vscode-lldb](https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb/blob/master/MANUAL.md) extension and it works fine, all other solutions I found don't work for me.

You still have to create configuration files, here are mine to debug my unit tests:

> I'm using googletest and extension c++14 in this example

**tasks.json**

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "build & debug tests",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "g++",
      "args": [
        "-g",
        "-std=c++14",
        "-I/src",
        "-lgtest",
        "tests/MainTest.cpp",
        "-o",
        "bin/testMain"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$gcc"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations":
  [
    {
      "name": "Debug Tests C/C++",
      "type": "lldb",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/testMain",
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/tests",
      "preLaunchTask": "build & debug tests"
    }
  ]
}
```